# Text in title bar or tint2 panel only to show name of program

Tags: xfce, manjaro, tint2

I’d like to only see the name of the program in the title so that it is also shown like this in the panel. Is it possible to set that globally in Manjaro?
I use tint2. Could it alternatively be set there?

[image]

For example, instead of “(2) Latest Newbie […] - Mozilla Firefox” I just want to display “Mozilla Firefox”. And instead of “untitled - Atom”, only “Atom” would be nice.

Reason is that with e.g. document titles or tab names show as task buttons on the panel, it becomes a bit harder to select the desired program when just having a quick glance.

OS: Manjaro XFCE
Panel: Tint2

Edit: found this for KDE

https://github.com/seanmadsen/kustom-window-title

Could something similar work for XFCE?

Answer (score 0):

Can be closed. Found a solution with wmctrl

`while [ 1 ]; do wmctrl -r firefox -T "Firefox "  ; done`